# Full width bootstrap html/css table does not work

Tags: html, css

```
        <div id="container">
            <div class="table-responsive bordered fill">

                    <div class="row fill-row">
                            <div class="w-50" id="image_1"></div>                      
                            <div class="w-50" id="image_1"></div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="row fill-row">
                            <div class="w-50" id="image_1"></div>                            
                            <div class="w-50" id="image_1"></div>
                    </div>

            </div>
        </div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/4b36yozr/
How I can remove the white vertical bar at the right of container despite it's set to be full width. I need to have 4 blocks that cover all the screen without that white space at right.

Comment: Add `margin:0` to your row class. Bootstrap gives it a 15px margin on each side.

Comment: it is caused by the .row class. specifically margin-left:-15px; override that and it will fix your problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give margin as 0px to  the class `fill-row` and you get it with no space at the right corner.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Efficienza Energia S.p.a.</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-ggOyR0iXCbMQv3Xipma34MD+dH/1fQ784/j6cY/iJTQUOhcWr7x9JvoRxT2MZw1T" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <style>
    #container {
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
      min-width: 100%;
      display: block;

    }

    html,
    body {
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .fill {
      min-height: 100%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      width: 100%;
    }

    .fill-row {
      min-height: 50%;
      max-width: 100%;
      height: 50%;
      width: 100%;
      /*margin-here*/
      margin:0px;
    }

    #image_1 {
      background-image: url("https://www.crockerriverside.org/sites/main/files/imagecache/pod/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg");
      width: 100%;
      height: 100%;
      background-repeat: no-repeat;
      background-size: auto;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="container">
    <div class="table-responsive bordered fill">

      <div class="row fill-row">
        <div class="w-50" id="image_1">
        </div>
        <div class="w-50" id="image_1">
        </div>
      </div>

      <div class="row fill-row">
        <div class="w-50" id="image_1">
        </div>
        <div class="w-50" id="image_1">
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

I have commented in the code where the margin has to be set to zero.

Answer (score 0):

Remove margin style from class row/fill-row.

Answer (score 0):

Adding the style below should remove the white space on the right

```
.fill-row {
    margin: 0; 
}
```

What seems to be happening was that the .row class was adding the following styles:

```
margin-right: -15px;
margin-left: -15px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use `container-fluid` and remove the padding from the columns, and also don't forget to set `<body>` height and width to `100vh` and `100%`, respectively. Like so:

```
<body>
  <div class="full">
    <div class="container-fluid half">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-6 nopadding">
          <div id="image_1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 nopadding">
          <div id="image_1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="container-fluid half">
      <div class="row h-100">
        <div class="col-6 nopadding">
          <div id="image_1"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 nopadding">
          <div id="image_1"></div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>  
</body>
```

And the css:

```
body {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
}

.full {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.half {
  height: 50vh;
}

.nopadding {
  padding: 0;
}

#image_1{
  background-image:url("https://www.crockerriverside.org/sites/main/files/imagecache/pod/main-images/camera_lense_0.jpeg");
  width:100%;
  height:100%;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
  background-size:auto;
}
```